# Warning: Undefined array key / Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null al generar un PDF en FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy generando reportes en PDF para mi sistema mediante la librería FPDF, estoy usando la misma estructura que he utilizado en los reportes anteriores que generé, pero con este en especifico me sale la siguiente cadena de errores:

> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\arepas\assets\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1525
>
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\arepas\assets\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1526
>
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\arepas\assets\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1530
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\arepas\assets\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1530

Este es el código con el que estoy generando el PDF

```
<?php
require('/xampp/htdocs/arepas/assets/fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('/xampp/htdocs/arepas/assets/imagenes/fondopdf.png', 0, 0, 220, 300);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',18);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(60);
    // Título
    $this->Cell(70,40,'Lista de clientes.',0,0,'C');
    
    
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(50);
    $this-> Cell(10, 10,'ID', 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $this-> Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode('Nombre cliente'), 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $this-> Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('Teléfono'), 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $this-> Cell(30, 10, utf8_decode('Dirección'), 1, 1, 'I', 0);
}

// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
    // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Número de página
    $this->Cell(0,10, utf8_decode('SIALC || Página ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}
include("/xampp/htdocs/arepas/db.php");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `lista_clientes_`";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $pdf->Cell(10, 10, $row['id_cliente_'], 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode($row['nombre_cliente_']) , 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['telefono_'], 0, ",", ".", 1, 0, 'I', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['direccion_'], 0, ",", ".", 1, 1, 'I', 0);

}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Este es el fragmento del código de fpdf.php en donde aparecen las líneas en las que se supone que está el problema:

```
protected function _putlinks($n)
{
    foreach($this->PageLinks[$n] as $pl)
    {
        $this->_newobj();
        $rect = sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F',$pl[0],$pl[1],$pl[0]+$pl[2],$pl[1]-$pl[3]);
        $s = '<</Type /Annot /Subtype /Link /Rect ['.$rect.'] /Border [0 0 0] ';
        if(is_string($pl[4])) 
            $s .= '/A <</S /URI /URI '.$this->_textstring($pl[4]).'>>>>';
        else
        {
            $l = $this->links[$pl[4]]; //línea 1525
            if(isset($this->PageInfo[$l[0]]['size'])) //línea 1526
                $h = $this->PageInfo[$l[0]]['size'][1];
            else
                $h = ($this->DefOrientation=='P') ? $this->DefPageSize[1]*$this->k : $this->DefPageSize[0]*$this->k;
            $s .= sprintf('/Dest [%d 0 R /XYZ 0 %.2F null]>>',$this->PageInfo[$l[0]]['n'],$h-$l[1]*$this->k); //línea 1530
        }
        $this->_put($s);
        $this->_put('endobj');
    }
}
```

Puse campo por campo para saber desde dónde se genera el problema, y parece que saltan los errores cuando incluyo

```
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['telefono_'], 0, ",", ".", 1, 0, 'I', 0);
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['direccion_'], 0, ",", ".", 1, 1, 'I', 0);
```

Comprobé mediante un echo que no estuvieran vacías las variables, y en efecto contienen la información que deberían traer. Si intento traer solamente el campo de *id* y *nombre del cliente* funciona de maravilla.

También comparé todo el código con otro de un reporte que sí está funcionando, pero no encontré ninguna diferencia a priori que pudiera estar ocasionando el problema, incluso el esquema de la consulta sql es el mismo.

Estoy atenta a cualquier solución que me puedan ofrecer, gracias de antemano. Si necesitan más información me lo hacen saber :)

Comment: mira revisa bien que el objeto $this->links contenga un valor llamado $pl[4]. debes verificar que `$pl`tenga algún valor, necesariamente el 4, las lineas despues de la 1525 dependen de esta pues alli se genera el valor de ella, si esta no es corregida las demas no funcionarán

Comment: Depura tu código. Comenta temporalmente el código que genera el PDF y coloca esto dentro del bucle: `foreach($this->PageLinks[$n] as $pl){  var_dump($pl); }`  Así podrás ver lo que te está generando la llamada a `PageLinks()`. Si no encuentras el problema agrega el resultado del `var_dump()` a la pregunta pulsando en [edit] y podremos ayudarte con más propiedad.

Comment: Al final eliminé el archivo y volví a escribir el código. Funcionó a la primera. Gracias a ambos por sus respuestas.